# Issue deleting 1 to (0..1) "child" record with same primary key?

Tags: breeze

For example we have a *Parent* table:

- ParentID (primary key)
- ParentType

...and depending on ParentType there are a few other detail tables, eg *ParentType1Detail*:

- ParentID (primary key)
- some more fields specific to a type 1 parent

Both *Parent* and *ParentType1Detail* have the same ParentID primary key forming a 1 to (0..1) relationship.

Now consider a situation in Breeze where we have an existing *Parent* and *ParentType1Detail* in the cache.  The user changes the *Parent* to "Type2" so we want to delete the *ParentType1Detail* record.  When we call parentType1Detail.entityAspect.setDeleted() Breeze seems to also go back and zero out the ParentID property on the *Parent* entity, thereby killing the parents primary key!

This would make sense for a normal relationship where the *Parent* has ChildID property that the detail table is keyed on but doesn't work if the joining property is also part of the parent's primary key.

I apologise if this is not clear or has already been discussed but I'd appreciate any suggestions about how to handle the above (without refactoring the database too much).  Or perhaps Breeze can handle this scenario and our EF configuration is wrong somehow?

---

**Update: Hack to resolve issue (hopefully)**

Buried in *defaultPropertyInterceptor* there is the following code:

```
// update fk data property
if (property.relatedDataProperties) {
    if (!entityAspect.entityState.isDeleted()) {
        var inverseKeyProps = property.entityType.keyProperties;
        inverseKeyProps.forEach(function(keyProp, i ) {
            var relatedDataProp = property.relatedDataProperties[i];
            var relatedValue = newValue ? newValue.getProperty(keyProp.name) : relatedDataProp.defaultValue;
            that.setProperty(relatedDataProp.name, relatedValue);
        });
    }
}
```

We've inserted a test to suppress changes if the related property is part of the entities key:

```
// update fk data property
if (property.relatedDataProperties) {
    if (!entityAspect.entityState.isDeleted()) {
        var inverseKeyProps = property.entityType.keyProperties;
        inverseKeyProps.forEach(function(keyProp, i ) {
            var relatedDataProp = property.relatedDataProperties[i];

            // Do not trash related property if it is part of that entity's key
            if (newValue || !relatedDataProp.isPartOfKey) {
                var relatedValue = newValue ? newValue.getProperty(keyProp.name) : relatedDataProp.defaultValue;
                that.setProperty(relatedDataProp.name, relatedValue);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for taking so long to look at this.  I like your suggestion for a fix. I will try to incorporate it in the next version of Breeze, and will post back here when it gets in.  And thx for contributing :)